How to get the path of a process after pivot_root in Linux
Is it possible to find the full path of a process after pivot_root? For example the command: readlink -f /proc/<pid>/exe returns /usr/bin/<program>, but it is not correct - it should be /pathToNewRoot/usr/bin/<program>. I tried:
ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe
lsof -p <pid>
realpath /proc/<pid>/exe

The result was always the same.
